# selenium web driver - css selector/locator for table hearder

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

```
<table id="state_table" class="table" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="column_checkbox disabled">
<th class="sortable desc" data-type="stateid">ID</th>
<th class="sortable" data-type="name">Name</th>
```

webdriver code to sort the table by column header is

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("th.sortable")).click();
```

This sorts the table by ID column. How do I sort the table by Name column using "Name" and not the data type="name"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother with css? Using XPath, that should be something like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[text()='Name']")).click();
```

Comment: thanks !! was trying to use css since the xpath I could think of was //table[@id='state_table']/thead/tr/th[4] ... which is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

We can use the CSS here

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sortable[data-type='name']")) -- Data Type(Name)
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sortable[data-type='stateid']")) -- Data Type (State ID)

Please Let me know is the above CSS Selectors are working.